# How to disable uncommited reads in Postgres synchronous replication?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I have set up PostgreSQL 9.5 with synchronous replication, see:

```
postgres=# show synchronous_commit;
 synchronous_commit 
--------------------
 on
```

Assume I have

```
postgres=# select * from test;
 id | value  
----+--------
  1 | value1
```

Then if I shut down the synchronous standby and issue

```
update test set value = 'value2' where id = 1;
```

it hangs (because the standby hasn't acknowledge it), as expected.

However, if I now press Ctrl-C, I get:

```
^CCancel request sent
WARNING:  canceling wait for synchronous replication due to user request
DETAIL:  The transaction has already committed locally, but might not have been replicated to the standby.
UPDATE 1
```

and then **the new, only locally committed value shows up in queries!**

```
postgres=# select * from test;
 id | value
----+--------
  1 | value2
```

Why is that?

Why does Postgres allow me to read something that is not written to at least 2 machines as I have configured it? I expected to read the old data, `value1`.

Can I change its behaviour to return only synchronously committed data?

Relevant unanswered questions:

- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.postgresql.devel.general/194555

Relevant code:

- https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/1d25779284fe1ba08ecd57e647292a9deb241376/src/backend/replication/syncrep.c#L251

Comment: I have just tested it: the `synchronous_commit = 'remote_apply'` feature in Postgres 9.6 doesn't help here either.

Comment: Sync replication's data masking is limited. The un-replicated xacts are also made visible if the upstream node is restarted, since the masking state is not persistent. I would very much like to see this improve but haven't had time to work on a persistent sync rep masked xact state feature myself.

Comment: OK, so the problem here is that just reading a value doesn't guarantee that it's replicated.
However, having a write return does guarantee it.
Knowing this, @CraigRinger do you know if the problem can be worked around by ensuring I always do an update and waiting for it to return before I assume that something is safely replicated? E.g. read a value, then do an `UPDATE` or `INSERT ON CONFLICT UPDATE` with the same value I have read? Or will the master not try to replicate this update if it doesn't change a value?

Comment: I've just tried my suggestion from above: Both `update test SET id = 1, value = 'value1' where id = 1 and value = 'value1';` and `insert into test values (1, 'value1') ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET value = 'value1';` seem to provide a workaround in that they hang when the standby is down, so they can be used to ensure that data is replicated (will happen when the update/insert returns) without modifying the database. So doing this after an unsafe `SELECT` acts as a safe `SELECT` that guarantees the previous `SELECT` was the replicated value.

Comment: Or even better as a safe `SELECT`: `update test SET id = id where id = 1 RETURNING id, value;` Of course this turns reads into no-op replicated writes so there is a performance penalty to doing this, but at least it's safe until postgres is fixed and transaction masking works.

Comment: The master will replicate the change even if it doesn't change the value. More importantly, performance will be *awful*, and it'll cause severe bloat to the tables, really bad concurrency due to locking issues, lots of deadlocks, etc. Definitely don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

It is a shortcoming of the feature as it is now, like Craig Riger explained.

Note that a synchronous replication setup with only one standby, where the standby is down, is to be considered down or dysfunctional. That's why you need at least two synchronous standby servers if you don't want to *reduce* your availibility.

Comment: "is to be considered down or dysfunctional" -- fully agreed, and that's why I'd expect it to NOT make my writes appear as if everything was OK!

Comment: I don't really like the current implementation of sync rep. I'd much rather we kept a record in the clog (which tracks whether an xact is in-progress, aborted, or committed) of whether the xact is replicated yet. Then use that to control xact visibility. Or perhaps keep a separate map of pending-replication xacts in memory, write an xlog record when one is confirmed and write the map out at each checkpoint, and use that to filter visibility. 

We don't do that right now, and  as far as I know nobody's working on it or funding work on it. Patches are of course welcome.